# Just got approved for Japan visa, but the passport got damaged

Tags: visas, passports, japan, passport-stamps, indonesia

I have just been approved for a Japanese visa, but then my passport got washed and now it is water damaged. The stamps are faded but the chips are still working (I checked them using NFC).

I'm contemplating applying for a new Indonesian passport, will the electronic Japan visa carry over to the new one?

Answer (score 1):

Looking on-line only a visa with more than one-year validity remaining is allowed for transfer.
https://www.sg.emb-japan.go.jp/files/000352903.pdf

Most electronic visas are linked by your passport number so if it's an electronic one I would say that with a new passport it would not be linked.